# Python Flask Selecting Multiple Buttons from Different Button Groups and pass them to HREF

Tags: python, html, flask

I am making a simple web-based questionnaire. It consists of two questions and the user needs to click on one of the scales (from 1 to 5) at each question, and then click submit button to go to the next page.

[image]

However, given the current circumstances, I could only click one button out of those ten.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">        
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container"><hr>

    {% for question, question_desc in questions.items() -%}
        <h2>{{ question_desc }}</h2>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-4" align="right">
                <a class="btn btn-link disabled btn-lg" disabled>{{ scales_description[question]['least'] }}</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                    {% for i in scales -%}
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">{{ i }}</button>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor -%}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4" align="left">
                <a class="btn btn-link disabled btn-lg" disabled>{{ scales_description[question]['most'] }}</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    {% endfor -%}

        <hr><a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Submit</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Tried to modify the code in accordance to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147512/multiple-button-groups-selection-issue), but still it was not working (I used label instead of button). Indeed I could select multiple buttons, however, I could select all the buttons. While my objective is to select only one within one group. Further, the circle inside the button is visible.

```
<div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    {% for i in scales -%}
    <div class="btn-group">
    <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">{{ i }}</button>-->
    <label for="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><input type="radio">{{ i }}</label>
</div>
{% endfor -%}
</div>
```

[image]

So my first question is how to make my code works for selecting only one button within a group? My second question is how to pass the values from selected buttons into href, so that user could navigate to the next page to see the recap of his/her selections? Here is the example of the next page incase user selected 3 and 3 as the answers.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot!

[image]

**STRUCTURE AND FULL CODES**

```
/my_app
/my_app
    __init__.py
    views.py

/static
    /css
        ...
    /fonts
        ...
    /js
        ...

/templates
    index.html
    next_page.html
run.py
```

> run.py

```
#!flask/bin/python
from my_app import app
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open_new('http://127.0.0.1:5000')
app.run(debug=True)
```

> **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask('templates')

from my_app import views
```

> views.py

```
from my_app import app
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/')
def root():
    questions = {
                 'question_1':'This is a question related to frequency',
                 'question_2':'This is a question related to painfulness'
                }
    scales = list(range(1,6))
    desc = {
            'question_1':{'least':'seldom', 'most':'often'},
            'question_2':{'least':'not at all', 'most':'so painful'}
           }

    return render_template('index.html',
                           questions = questions,
                           scales = scales,
                           scales_description = desc)

@app.route('/next_page/<selected_scale_q1>/<selected_scale_q2>/')
def next_page(selected_scale_q1, selected_scale_q2):

    selected_scale = {
                      'question_1': {'question':'This is a question related to frequency', 'answer':selected_scale_q1},
                      'question_2': {'question':'This is a question related to painfulness', 'answer':selected_scale_q2}
                     }

    return render_template('next_page.html', selected_scale = selected_scale)
```

> index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">        
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container"><hr>

        {% for question, question_desc in questions.items() -%}
            <h2>{{ question_desc }}</h2>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-4" align="right">
                    <a class="btn btn-link disabled btn-lg" disabled>{{ scales_description[question]['least'] }}</a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                        {% for i in scales -%}
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">{{ i }}</button>-->
                            <label for="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><input type="radio">{{ i }}</label>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor -%}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4" align="left">
                    <a class="btn btn-link disabled btn-lg" disabled>{{ scales_description[question]['most'] }}</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        {% endfor -%}

            <hr><a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Submit</a>
            <!--<hr><a href="/next_page/3/3/" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Submit</a>-->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> next_page.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">        
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container"><hr>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6" align="center"><h2>Question</h2></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" align="center"><h2>Answer</h2></div>
            </div>

            {% for question_seq, dictionary in selected_scale.items() -%}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6" align="left"><h2>{{ dictionary['question'] }}</h2></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" align="center"><h2>{{ dictionary['answer'] }}</h2></div>
            </div>
            {% endfor -%}

            <hr><a href="/" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Back to home page</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```